# Copying xpath element is not working on Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I tried to some python code that visits twitter > copy the "Happening now" text. But it didn't work.

```
import webbrowser

print("Visiting Twitter.com...")
webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open_new('https://twitter.com')
content = webbrowser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
```

**ERROR:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 5, in 
content = webbrowser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
AttributeError: module 'webbrowser' has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: What is the error you are having? Can you share error output

Comment: @burakhan-aksoy I have updated the error as well. Please re-check.

Comment: @silva2021 did my answer resolved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the browser!
You have to do something like  `driver = new ChromeDriver();` first.
Additionally, you should add some wait condition before reading the text from the element, something like `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));`
The code I presented is in `Java`, but it's quite similar in `Python`

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the source code in webbrowser.py file, I can't see anything related to 'find_element_by_xpath' attribute, hence I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/burakhanaksoy/Desktop/untitled folder/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    content = webbrowser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
AttributeError: module 'webbrowser' has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

My suggestion to you is to use selenium if you want to go for xpath. And you should refrain from using div/div/div type of xpaths since your code can easily break once twitter adds another div there.

If you want to find "Happening Now" text through xpath, you should use something like `//*[contains(text(),'Happening Now')]`

You can start with -> https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Answer (score 0):

personally, i hate using XPath because it's confusing and give me a lot of unnecessary errors

I always use CSS selector because it is easier and more reliable

```
webbrowser.find_element_by_css_selector('put_css_selector_here')
```

if you don't know how css selectors work [click this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1mER1bV0N0)